# Mathias placeholder plugin bug on IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net, placeholder

so I implemented this [placeholder plugin](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder) and have this bug on IE8

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ctlUsername" runat="server" placeholder="User ID" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:TextBox ID="ctlPassword" runat="server" placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="12"></asp:TextBox>
```

where the User ID placeholder becomes the value of the textbox, which I dont like :(

by the way this text box has focus onload.

the password works perfectly :)

and this is my jquery

```
 $('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a bug as IE8 does not support the `placeholder` option. Adding it as a value and removing it on focus and vice versa is probably how the plugin handles older browsers. Try a different method if you don't like this plugin.

Comment: Ah... I found out its about the focus that triggered on page load in the c#. so i removed it and place as a <script> on the the html page..